# Facebook Graph API 2.0 alternative to link_stat

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

I wanted to know the count of the no. of people that have shared/posted a link of my website on Facebook. I came across [link_stat](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat) that I think will do what I need. The only problem is that FQL is slowly being discouraged and I fear that the code I write today may get deprecated someday.
Is there anyway to accomplish what I'm trying to do purely using the Graph API? Or maybe Facebook Insights?
I have an app that I have associated to my website and have put it's APP_ID on every page of the website.
If there is such a way, perhaps someone could post a sample link using the [Graph Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/).

Comment: With link_stat you can only query single URLs, not a whole domain. Do you want to do that? Otherwise have a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/insights/#claiming_a_domain

Comment: I'd want to query one link at a time.

Comment: I have claimed the domain and attached it to the app. In the Insights for my app I can see about 3 stories published but what I don't know is how to query for this? In the Insights Reference Page which insight can I try use? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/insights